# Multiple labels in match painfully slow?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher query that looks like this

```
START user=node(8313)
MATCH user-->contact:X-->endpoint1:Y-[r1?]->another:Z
WHERE r1 IS null
RETURN user;
```

It seems to hang Neo4J 2.0.0-M05.

If i run the query without one the labels it seems to be working better

```
START user=node(8313)
MATCH user-->contact:X-->endpoint1-[r1?]->another:Z
WHERE r1 IS null
RETURN user;
```

Should i not use multiple labels in a match?

Also, it seems after i ran this queries for a while my nodes increased a lot? I started out on about 250 and now, without i can rembembering adding anything, have 16k nodes and 100k+ relationships.

Comment: Are the nodes stats from the webconsole? The webconsole stats seem to be quiet buggy, and I wouldnt rely on them. It often tells me that I have thousands of nodes, when I know exactly that I dont.

Comment: Yeah the stats is from the webconsole, maybe thats not an issue then. But the other still is.

Comment: We're looking into this Lars. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Glad to see this bug identified. For StackOverflow, this question appears to be off-topic because it is specific to an identified bug in a Neo4j 2,0 milestone build (e.g. beta) and has been [reported as such](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/M37UXe8qnDQ). This is very useful information but there's no answer that can really be posted aside from 'we fixed the bug.' I believe it should be closed, but not deleted, so at least others who stumble into this have a landing zone.

Answer (score 0):

This is now a verified bug:

[Read more on Neo4j google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/M37UXe8qnDQ)

Comment: I came across this issue and gave up without asking.. Thanks for taking it to SO and Google Groups. and thanks for reporting!